# SpriteKit snake - joints and physics

Tags: sprite-kit, physics, skphysicsbody, jointjs, skphysicsjoint

I'm working on my game - Snake for iOS.

My development has already passed this stage, however I think about doing some refinements to it. After several tries and errors I've totally ignored physics/movement and collision detection offered by SpriteKit and I keep using my own implementation. Perhaps with your help I may refactor this parts of the game.

My snake can turn in all possible directions (360 degree). There is no gravity. How would you set up your physic bodies if you would prefer to offset as much as a code to existing SpriteKit implementation?

There are two important parts I think.

First - joints. Snake is constructed from multiple physic bodies. All bodies simply follow one another - going through all the points that the head was some time ago. I assume the best joint for this is Pin joint? I used Pin joints with anchor point exactly between neighbouring bodies. But this setup caused the rest of the snake's body to change the physics of the head. It shouldn't be like that. I tried changing the weight to zero, putting linear and angular dumping to maximum. The result was never acceptable.

Second - controlling movement. The movement of the snake is constant. User by pressing left and right button starts gentle movement of the snake to the right or left. Do you think I should in the update method reset the snake's velocity each time to my constant value? Or should I play with forces impulses and torques? The turning only takes place when user keeps pressing the screen - it takes few seconds to reverse the snake (like "u-turn") - how about rotating it?

Any suggestion is appreciated. Best regards.

Comment: Your question is too broad, if you want some help you must write some part of your code, please look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388005/spritekit-joint-follow-the-body

Comment: Ok I will take a look.